# WP_Query to find any published post with ID greater than given ID

Tags: wp-query

With WP_Query, I want to retrieve all the published posts with ID greater than a particular ID. Is this possible?

I could not find any way. I tried many variations of this, but I don't get the expected result:

```
 apply_filters(
                'widget_posts_args',
                array(
                    'posts_per_page'      => 20,
                    'no_found_rows'       => true,
                    'post_status'         => 'publish',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'ID',
                            'value'   => 296380,
                            'type'    => 'numeric'
                            'compare' => '>',
                            ),
                        )
                )
            )
```

Of course, I tried the meta_query alone too but this one returns some old posts, NOT posts with ID greater than 296380.

I tried the following too, but they either return the same posts as the previous query or the same posts with some correctly retrieved post:

```
array(
        'meta_query' =>
        array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_date',
                'value' => strtotime( '2024-01-16' ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        )
    )

array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => '2024-01-16',
                'before' => '2032-01-01',
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is possible with eg posts_where SQL filter, but what about using a built-in date query filtering instead in WP_Query?

Comment: @birgire It can be done with date too (I have not tried), but why it doesn't work with ID? In SQL this would be quite simple

Comment: Why  mess with sql strings if WP_Query supports date filtering via input arguments :-)

Comment: @birgire I can do this easily with SQL strings, I don't care if they are ugly   :-)  Problem is I can't get what I want with any other WP-native method

Comment: I mentioned the name of the SQL filter above, but I would first look into e.g. date_query argument here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ but not the meta_query you tried.

Comment: @birgire: it half works: that is, this one correctly returns some post, but returns very old posts too

Comment: @birgire Don't worry, I go SQL with wpdb. Thanks for your kind suggestions  :-)

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Note that by "meta query", it means "search in the post meta table, i.e. `wp_postmeta` in default installation", so your first meta query will result in a query which looks like `wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ID' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '296380'` and *not* `wp_posts.ID > 296380`. And yes, you can use `$wpdb` directly to get the full post data or just the post IDs, but what you're trying to do can be achieved via a single `WP_Query`, just as shown in @birgire's answer, where he used the hook `posts_where` to add the custom SQL query.

Comment: So you should do the same, i.e. use `WP_Query`, which among others, ensures that plugins can filter the query when necessary. But it should be noted that greater ID does not mean the post is new(er), so if your goal is to get the posts posted *or modified* after the post 296380, then a date query like this would do it - `'date_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( 'after'  => '2024-01-16', 'column' => 'post_date', ), array( 'after'  => '2024-01-16', 'column' => 'post_modified', ), )`

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks, but I ended up using SQL, it was easier for me (to maintain too!)   :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the date query doesn't work because of modified post dates (e.g. if the posts' timeline is no longer linear), here's a `posts_where` filter's suggestion (untested):

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where, $query ) use ( &$wbdb ) {
    $id = $query->get( '_id__gt' );    
    if( is_int( $id ) && $id > 0 ) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " AND %i.ID > %d ",
            "{$wpdb->posts}",
            $id
        );
    }       
    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```

to support this type of `_id__gt` argument in `WP_Query` for ID greater than some positive integer number:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    '_id__gt'      => 296380,    // <-- our new input argument!
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But using queries based on some given ID values in production, sounds brittle.

Comment: I ended up directly using SQL, but thanks. Why brittle? I know the ID of the latest post, so I want to retrieve all the posts published after that ID (if any). In my scenario, I have no date/time information available, so the only thing I can use is the ID.

Comment: You get e.g. pagination for free with WP_Query so it will be easier for large number of posts to filter through. You also miss out other things, like caching. One might also have different IDs between local, dev, staging and production install. Additionally import/export tools might not preserve IDs. @LifeafterGuest

Comment: I don't need pagination and caching is the exact reason of the code I'm editing: I have an old widget that loads news when the homepage first loads. When people come back to the website, they often don't find the news updated, for cache issues. So I modified the widget to refresh the news on every page load. It's a low traffic website, nothing really important. To avoid large amount of data, I don't ask for the latest 50 posts, but the posts published after the one displayd (generally a couple). Then I edit the DOM accordingly.